Different results using rma.mv: Mods vs. Subset
I am conducting a three-level meta-analysis in R using metafor. While computing a subgroup analysis I noted that the assumed summary effect of one subgroup differs from the one I would get while doing the same analysis only for the specific subgroups (as laid out in http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates). The problem is that although the difference in estimates is not huge, the conclusion still somewhat depends on what summary effect I choose. I would therefore appreciate any help with choosing the correct approach.
Here is some pseudo code to illustrate my problem:
rma.mv(
    yi = yi, 
    V = vi,
    mod = ~ Moderator-1,
    random = ~ 1 | study_id / es_id, # effect sizes nested in each paper
    slab = paste0(author, ", ", year),
    data = my_data,
    method = "REML",
    digits = 3
  )

# versus #
rma.mv(
    yi = yi, 
    V = vi,
    subset = Moderator == "Moderator Level 1",
    random = ~ 1 | study_id / es_id, # effect sizes nested in each paper
    slab = paste0(author, ", ", year),
    data = my_data,
    method = "REML",
    digits = 3
  )


As described under the link, you could do a likelihood ratio test comparing a model that allows the variance components to differ across moderator levels versus the first model you fitted that assumes equal variances across moderator levels.
